# Error: Binding reference of type '<type>&' to 'const <type> discards qualifiers'

Tags: c++, c++14

I use a struct to store some set of data and I use a std::set to store that struct objects. (std::set is used to find a struct object when needed)
Following is the sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
struct S
{
  int x; // will be mandatory for the std::set operations
  char *name; // just a data
  S(int a, char *n): x(a), name (NULL)
  {
    name = strdup(n);
    cout << "constructor" << endl;
  }
  ~S()
  {
    free(name);
    name = NULL;
  }
  S(const S &s)
  {
    cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
    name = strdup(s.name);
    x = s.x;
   }
   bool operator< (const S &s) const // to support for std::set insert operation
   {
      return x < s.x;
   }
   bool operator== (const S &s) const // to support for std::set find operation
   {
     return x == s.x;
   }
}

static void updateStr(S &s)
{
  free(s.name);
  s.name = strdup((char*)"another");
}

int main()
{
   set<S> st;
   st.insert(S(2, (char*)"abc"));
   cout << "1: " << endl;
   set<S>::iterator i = st.find(S(2, (char*)"dummy"));
   cout << "2: " << endl;
   if(i != st.end())
   {
      S &s = (*i); /*Issue occurs here*/ // don't want to make a copy, just need the existing item in the set.
      updateStr(s); // need to modify 'name' attribute, not the 'x' attribute
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This code gives "error: binding reference of type ‘S&’ to ‘const S’ discards qualifiers" error when I try to access struct object in the set by reference.
How do I resolve this issue?
(My actual struct is having more malloced data attributes, and the struct can not be separated into 'a key' and 'values'.)

Comment: Don't use C-style casts. And don't cast const away. That way lies undefined behaviour.

Comment: You are not allowed to modify elements of a `std::set` in place (via an iterator), as they are ordered (and any such modification could break the ordering)

Comment: You can't change an item in `std::set`.  You need to make a copy of the item, `erase` the item in the `std::set`, then modify the copy of the item, then `insert` the copy back in.

Comment: @Eljay For C++17 users passing by: extract, modify, insert is better than erasing.

Comment: You must check the result of `strdup()`. You should also add move semantic to avoid needless copies of the string. The constructor for S as is should take a `const char*` so you don't have to illegally cast the const away for "abc".

Comment: One way around is to mark `name` member `mutable`. Then you can update it on `const S&`